# Vimeo API request with AngularJs "401 Authorization required"

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, vimeo-api

I've been trying to call an external API (Vimeo) from my AngularJS code, using $http.jsonp. But all i get is a 401 Authorization required even though i added my authorization Key to the header.  had a similar problem doing the same thing with jQuery.ajax(). But with jQuery i solved the problem by setting the beforeSend function to set my authorization key on the request Header using the xhr object.

My code:

```js
function(){
  var config = {
              headers: {Authorization: "bearer 34210aeac4e02a251b8821a53620e93c"},
              params : {
                  callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                  }
              };
  var url = "https://api.vimeo.com/tags/fun/videos?per_page=5";
  $http.jsonp(url, config).success(function(response){
      console.log(response);
  });
};
```

How do i get this to work. Is the some kind of config.beforeSend that i can use to set the header just like jQuery

Answer (score 1):

In angular you could use [http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

1. Define your http interceptor: this one will add a token on every http request

   ```
   ng.module('interceptors')
    .factory('authorizationInterceptor', function () {
       return {
           request: function (config) {
              config.headers = config.headers || {};
              config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' +  '34210aeac4e02a251b8821a53620e93c';
              return config;
          }
   };});
   ```
2. register your interceptor

   ```
   angular.module('myApp',[]).config(['$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authorizationInterceptor');
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
   }]);
   ```

Note, I think the first letter of bearer must be capital letter in you header

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Angular too well, but I think the issue is that you're using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  Since that uses the browser's script tag to get around CORS restrictions, it does not allow for verbs other than GET nor setting headers.

The Vimeo API supports CORS headers, so you actually want to make a regular GET request using the browser's AJAX functionality.  I believe that AngularJS provides for this with the `$http.get` function to do what you're currently doing ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)).

I would try out:

```
function(){
    var config = {
        headers: {Authorization: "Bearer 34210aeac4e02a251b8821a53620e93c"}
    };
    var url = "https://api.vimeo.com/tags/fun/videos?per_page=5";
    $http.get(url, config).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```